# Jquery Color Picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using color picker provided by http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Jquery Code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
        onSubmit: function (hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
            $(el).val('#' + hex);
            $(el).ColorPickerHide();
            borderColor = $('#tbcontentBorder').val();
            $('#news').css('border-color', borderColor);
        },
        onBeforeShow: function () {
            $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
        }
    }).bind('keyup', function () {

        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);

    });
});
```

html:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" id="colorSelector" value="00ff00" />
```

It always shows `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ColorPicker is not a function`. I tried debugging jQuery, and it is loading perfectly, but when the `ready` function executes, the `ColorPicker` function vanishes. I am using ajax controls as well. Could those controls be causing the problem?

Comment: Did you include the colorpicker js? Make sure it exists and it's loading correctly (After jquery).

Comment: Yes it is loading correctly i have debug the script it loading correctly but get vanish at the time of document.ready funcation

Comment: And make sure load colorpicker .js files AFTER jquery

Comment: Create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), and try to reproduce the issue. We need more code to diagnose this problem.

Comment: whats the `news` selector for?

Comment: i am using ajax controls on page is it making some problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried on separate test page and it get works. 
I make the changes in js library of colorpicker and it get start working. 
I think because of ajaxcontrol it is not working

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.fn.extend({
                ColorPicker: MyColorPicker.init,
                ColorPickerHide: MyColorPicker.hidePicker,
                ColorPickerShow: MyColorPicker.showPicker,
                ColorPickerSetColor: MyColorPicker.setColor
            });
            $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
                color: '#000',
                onShow: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onHide: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                    $('#colorSelector').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
                }
            });
            //            $('#<%=txtReserveType.ClientID %>')
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not included either css or JavaScript.
Please check this one [`Jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/c7xms870/) its working.